# React.useEffect missing dependency - state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm getting the error "React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency: 'openPosts'" where openPosts is state in a Hook.

```
export const Posts = (props) => {

  const [openPosts, setOpenPosts] = React.useState([]); *openPosts is an array of numbers*

  React.useEffect(_ => {
    let filteredOpenPosts = openPosts.filter(num => num >= 1);
    setOpenPosts(filteredOpenPosts);
  }, [props.userId]);
```

I've read around but I haven't understood why I'm getting this error. Can I ignore it?

I essentially want state to filter as above with a change in `props.userId` and thought this would be a clean way to do it. I could also create more state to track any change in `props.userId` but if the above can work I'd prefer it.

Comment: What is the likelyhood of `openPosts` changing if/when `userId` changes? By not including `openPosts` as a dependency of `useEffect` it simply means that if `openPosts` changes then your `useEffect` code won't re-run unless `userId` is also updated.

Comment: `openPosts` is updated each time `userId` changes. The behaviour you described is intentional.

Comment: Hi mista, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to specify the dependency, then you can try this,

```
React.useEffect(_ => {
    setOpenPosts(prevState => prevState.filter(num => num >= 1));
}, [props.userId]);
```